# How to create custom function to get WordPress Archives by year?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi people I know WP has its method to get archives year by calling wp_get_archives()

**But this method will get a list of archive years which on click it will redirect to all post of the year itself**.

I want to create a customize function just to get a list of years which I click on it will call a second query to get months and post counts.

example. after I click on the year I can get all available post by months of the year and its post count in each month.

anyone please help with the code to get to this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You could try use `wp_get_archives()` and then loop over them something like:</strike>

```
$args = array('echo' => false, 'type' => 'yearly');
$archives = wp_get_archives($args);

foreach($archives as $archive){
     // CODE FOR EACH YEAR ARCHIVE
}
```

I'm not completely sure what you're asking to do.

Answer above is no good anyway as wp_get_archives() only returns a string., which we can't loop over.

This was a tricky enough question as there doesn't seem to be a native way to do this, see my code below that should help you on your way:

```
<?php

      $months = array();
      for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
          $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
          $months[$m] = $month;
      }

      $earliest_year = 2016;
      $current_year = date('Y');
      $years = range($earliest_year, $current_year);

      foreach ($years as $year){

          echo '<h1>' . $year . '</h1>';

          foreach ($months as $monthnum => $month){

              $args = array(
                'year' => $year,
                'monthnum' => $monthnum
              );
              $posts = get_posts($args);

              if($posts){
                echo '<h2>' . $month . '(' . count($posts) . ')</h2>';
              }
              foreach($posts as $post){
                  if($post){
                      $post_id = $post->ID;
                      echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br>';
                  } //END if($post)

              } //END foreach($posts as $post)
          } //END foreach ($months as $monthnum => $month)
      } //END foreach ($years as $year)

?>
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions.

Comment: i know the $args but this method once get the archives years and click on the years it will redirect to the year posts archives. I don't want it to be clickable to content. i want to click on it and call a second query to get the months+post counts of the year itself

Comment: Ohhh you are almost there. but how do i edit it so that it only return the year in string while adding a id to each of the year tag so that i can use jquery later on to call second query to get the months(post count) of the year?

Comment: If you remove everything from: "if($posts){"  to  " } //END foreach($posts as $post)"  it will just leave the year string you can add and ID to the year string by editing this line: "echo '<h1>' . $year . '</h1>';" just add an ID to the H1 : "echo '<h1 id="year' . $year  .' ">' . $year . '</h1>';"

This will add an ID like year-2016

Comment: how to get all the past years i see there isa $earliest_year. how do i set it to default get all the available years of post i have.

Comment: Because i only want to display years according to those posts i have.

Comment: I'm just getting every year from the the earliest year I was assuming you have posts in every year from whatever the earliest year is? Otherwise you'd probably need another function go get the years containing posts.

Comment: I just learn to use the $args in wp_get_archives(). custom format how do I change the $args so that it return those years as a string without permalinks ? do you know? `<?php $sort = array(
 'type'            => 'yearly',
 'limit'           => '',
 'format'          => 'custom', 
 'before'          => '<div id="tlyear">',
 'after'           => '</div>&nbsp;',
 'show_post_count' => false,
 'echo'            => 1,
 'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_type'     => 'post'
);?>`
'

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the $args to do that. Although you could change 'echo' to 0, store your archives in a variables and then strip the tags and echo the formatted string. <?php $preformat = wp_get_archives( $sort ); $formatted = strip_tags($preformat); echo $formatted;?>

Comment: i wonder how to modify this by getting the available post months if i parse in a year parameter. return me the months(post_count) including its permalinks